# Intersection of line with polygon

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

We have a convex polygon P with n edges and a line L (not a line segment!).You are allowed to do some preprocessing .After preprocessing ,find whether the line intersects polygon in O(logn) time . Preferably , the preprocessing should be linear in both time and space.

edit :
Any ideas,may be in higher preproceesing time/space, would also be appreciated

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497841/optimal-algorithm-if-line-intersects-convex-polygon